# Rip edge : Yellow Ring disabled

Tags: modeling

When using the rip tool, there is usually a yellow ring displayed around the vertex I want to rip, I just click and drag on that circle to rip out. For some reason, the yellow circle won't show up anymore. Any idea where I can enable it?

Comment: If you select the icon on the left toolbar you'll see the circle but if you merely use the 'V' shortcut key to rip, the circle won't appear. That's by design.

Comment: Found my solution. In "Viewport Gizmos", Active Object was deselected. I checked the box and the ring is back!

Comment: That's the default setting so you must have changed it at some time.